# Iron Router Couldn't find a template named "layout" or "layout"

Tags: meteor, meteor-blaze

Been having weird errors for entire day after transiting to Meteor's new file structure. Iron-router seems to break down.

I do have layout.html and js files. Also names in proper lowercase.

**The full error:**

> Couldn't find a template named "layout" or "layout". Are you sure you
>   defined it?

**My files are:**

- client/main.html and main.js --> `<head></head>` is defined here
- import/ui/layouts --> contains layout.html and layout.js
  `<body></body>` is defined here.
- import/startup/both --> contains
  router.js

**router file:**

```
Router.configure({
   layoutTemplate    : 'layout',
   loadingTemplate   : 'loading',
   notFoundTemplate  : 'notFound',
   waitOn: function() {
      return [
         Meteor.subscribe('allUsers'),
         Meteor.subscribe('otherUser')
      ];
   }
});

Router.route('/',{ 
  name: 'home',
   onBeforeAction: function () {
      if( Meteor.userId() ){ 
         Router.go('/new'); 
      } else {
         this.next();
      }
   }
});
```

when i console.log `typeof(Template.layout)`, it returns undefined.

So when i moved both `layout.html` and `layout.js` up to client folder, together with `main.html`...the error disappeared but still showed blank page, but gave error that a page named "settings" is missing (but the settings.html and js files are both present in `import/ui/pages`. However console.log above returned an object. Strange.

**PS: On the side note**:

I tried `import '/imports/startup/client';` in the main.js file in the server folder to make the htmls above work. I got`'Error: Cannot find module '/imports/startup/client'`. So i just comment it out first to solve the above issue.

I also added `import '../imports/ui/layouts/layout.html';` or `import '../imports/ui/pages';` in the client main.js. But error says `Cannot find module '../imports/ui/pages'` and settings is still not visible to the system.

Anyone able to shed some light on this? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Leave your blaze html files in `/client` - html files cannot be imported as is. Your js files can be migrated to the `imports` directory structure but you'll have to export functions from each file and then import them where you need to use them. Personally I'm not sure it's worth migrating a blaze project to the new structure, it's much more useful if you're using react.

Comment: In the example given, Meteor mentioned imports has startup, ui...Where ui has individual pages. So that is purely for js and jsx? By client...Is it restricted to client main folder or also imports/startup/client?

Comment: In react there are only really js/jsx and css files, both of which can be imported. html files are not really used. Files under `/client` or its subdirectories are automatically minified, bundled and sent to the client but nothing under `imports` gets sent to the client unless it is imported. Normally `/client/main.js` performs the first import(s) and then the files it imports import other files and so on.

Answer (score 1):

This is how I do it with mine in router file:

```
import '../../ui/layouts/mainlayout.js';
```

You do not have to put your html files in the client folder.  I put mine in imports and with a generic page I do this in page.js:

`import ./page.html` then the rest of my code.